# Why is my javascript image gallery not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to HTML and css and very new to javascript.

I used a gallery generator called Highslide and did all the necessary instructions including uploading all the download files to the FTP and copying and pasting the code onto my site page.

Please could somebody perhaps decipher why the code on this page is not working? Really appreciate the help!

http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/shop.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the images are not available at the required place.
Below is the location where your image should be present i.e., under /images/thumbs.

http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/highslide/images/thumbs/vintage6.jpg

Comment: ah fab thank you yes I misplaced the folder. thats sorted however the javascript is now not working?

Comment: what i mean is that when i click on the image, it is suppose to enlarge in a gallery form, however it does not

Comment: @ChloeHammond, you have a missing closing double quote in `<link>`, it should be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative&text=SLATE,SHOP">`. This prevents your gallery script from loading and working correctly.

Comment: thankyou @Gyrocode.com that helped, then I needed to ensure all my source files were in the correct place.

Comment: @ChloeHammond, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider accepting answer, if Apoorv helped you out.